# Reduced schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On the book of algebraic geometry by Robin Hartshorne , about Chap 2 exercise 2.3(c). Let $f:X → Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and assume that $X$ is reduced. Show that there is a unique morphism $g:X → Y_{red}$ such that $f$ is obtained by composing $g$ with the natural map $Y_{red} → Y$.
I have tried many times and don't know how to deal it. Since $Y_{red}$ and $Y$ have the same underlying topological space, I tried to set $g=f$, but what about g#? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the "$g$-sharp" ?

Comment: @Mihail induced by g,g#:O_{Y_{red}} → g_*(O_X)  sheaves of rings on Y_{red}

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ is a ringhomomorphism and $I$ an ideal of $A$ such that $f(I)=0$, then it is basic algebra that $f$ factors through $A/I$. This is really all you need.

Comment: @Rieux got it, thank you! So first reduce situation to affine scheme

Comment: Well that's not really what I meant. In fact it is not necessary to reduce to the affine situation at all. You should rather try to prove the analogous statement in the general context of locally ringed spaces. But the basic algebra result I mentioned is still all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define $g$ on the affine patches. After that we will glue the morphisms(of course it is to be shown that they really glue, because they coincide on the intersections). Say $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} f: \Spec A \rightarrow \Spec B $ and $\Spec A$ is reduced. This map is induced by $f':B\rightarrow A$ with $A$ having no nilpotents. Now this map will factor through $g:B_{red}\rightarrow A$ where $\DeclareMathOperator{\Nil}{Nil} B_{red}:=B/\Nil(B)$ so that we kill all the nilpotents of $B$. The reason why it does factor in such way is $f'(b)=0$ for any $b\in \Nil(B)$. Justification: $b^n=0 \implies f'(b)^n=0 \implies f(b)=0$. And I guess the definition of $Y_{red}$ is exactly killing the nilpotents on every affine patch and gluing them together again.

Comment: Thank you! First consider affine scheme situation, and then glue these open affine sets which covers the scheme or these morphisms defined on each affine scheme. This is a common skill in algebraic geometry ?

Comment: @Jabin I encounter method of moving on from affine charts very often. I guess because a lot of notions for schemes and morphisms are defined through the affines. 

You can accept the answer if it solves your question.